# Matplotlib draw() Method Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use the draw() method from matplotlib to dynamically update a plot. I've tried simply using,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.draw()
```

but that literally doesn't do anything. The program executes and then shuts down without ever showing a plot. I ran the following program hoping that the show method would generate a plot window with the backend and then be updated, but all I get is that the backend draws the plot with the first show command and is subsequently never updated. I think the show() method is hanging the session until the window is closed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
time.sleep(1)
plt.plot(range(50))
plt.draw()
```

I'm running the latest version of Mac OS X (as of July,15 2014). Okay, so that didn't work. Next I tried to use a different backend than my default, ('tkagg'). I also enabled matplotlib's interactive mode (ion()).

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.ion()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
time.sleep(1)
plt.plot(range(50))
plt.draw()
```

Next, I'm thinking maybe the show() and draw() methods aren't necessary anymore so I deleted those. When I do that, the program executes and closes without showing a window.

How can I dynamically update a plot if the draw() method doesn't modify the canvas. When I use the pythong interpreter from the command line, this interactive mode stuff works, but as soon as I'm executing a file with "python myfile.py", it's not happening. I've downloaded and tried a million examples and none of them actually update a plot on my computer...help!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, try the `MacOSX` backed.

Comment: @Ben I gave that a go. That backend doesn't allow the window to plot either...

Comment: are you able to plot interactively from `ipython`?

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
plt.plot(range(50))
plt.show()
```

The above works for me. You need to close the first plot window in order to get the second one. This is because `plt.show()` is a blocking function. It blocks the program until you actually close the window.

If instead you want the plots in the same window. Then use the interactive mode in matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.ion()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.draw()
time.sleep(20)
plt.plot(range(50))
plt.draw()
time.sleep(20)
```

This does work, but, on my computer it does not open the plot window in the foreground. So, do a swipe up motion in OSX to find the window.

Comment: Of course that works, it's not my question, though. I'm talking about updating the plot in place. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I just updated the answer for this. See if it works.

Comment: Your second response does not work for me either. It looks like you're copy/pasting my code in responses without change.

Comment: When I run that same code, there are no plot windows anywhere on my mac. At all. The code pauses for 41.4 seconds, and finally finishes execution without creating a visible plot window.

Comment: Wierd. It works on my OSX 10.9, matplotlib 1.1.1 and python 2.7.

Comment: Are you sure the plot window is not open in the background?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive it isn't. Thy animated python dock icon pops and bounces, but no window...

Comment: Right click on that bouncing icon and select "Show all windows"

Comment: When I do that, it exposes into nothing.

Comment: The whole point of using `plt.ion()` is to update the plot in the same window, rather than in a new window. Any idea how to achieve that?